# Missing dependencies when running Cypress on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cypress, alpine-linux

I'm trying to get cypress to run on jenkins on a remote server (Platform: linux (Alpine Linux - 3.7.0). Every time I click 'Build now', it fails with this message:

```
+ npm install
npm WARN cypress_test@1.0.0 No repository field.

up to date in 1.217s
[Pipeline] sh (Run tests)
+ npx cypress run
It looks like this is your first time using Cypress: 4.7.0

[?25l[17:51:40]  Verifying Cypress can run /root/.cache/Cypress/4.7.0/Cypress [started]
[17:51:41]  Verifying Cypress can run /root/.cache/Cypress/4.7.0/Cypress [failed]
[?25hCypress failed to start.

This is usually caused by a missing library or dependency.

The error below should indicate which dependency is missing.

https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies

If you are using Docker, we provide containers with all required dependencies installed.

----------

spawn /root/.cache/Cypress/4.7.0/Cypress/Cypress ENOENT

----------

Platform: linux (Alpine Linux - 3.7.0)
Cypress Version: 4.7.0
[?25h[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Cypress's official doc https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#Advanced-setup
doesn't have an answer that works for me.

What dependency am I missing? Installing xvfb didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried using one of the OSes they suggest there, rather than alpine?

Comment: I don't have control over which OS is used on that aws server

Comment: Then have you looked at e.g. https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/419?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that thread - I hadn't come across it. It seems Cypress+Jenkins just won't work on Alpine-linux.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error in Linux machines. The solution has been provided in https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/introduction.html#Dependencies

```
sudo yum install -y xorg-x11-server-Xvfb gtk2-devel gtk3-devel libnotify-devel GConf2 nss libXScrnSaver alsa-lib
```